# How to elegantly modify html to inject html element after x-th paragraph on the server side?

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, html-agility-pack, sitecore8

I need to modify html coming from external file (server side) before I render it and inject a quote 'component' like this:
[image]

This component needs to be injected after 2nd paragraph and I'm planning to use htmlagillity pack. Any examples? Is HtmlNode.InsertAfter() method good choice once I found third paragraph which should be trivial.

Another question is would it be possible to inject sitecore placeholder or even usercontrol that is going to render my quote instead of pure html? I feel it should be but not sure what would be good approach.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest two possible approaches here:

1) Use snippets with some customisation. Snippets allow users to insert pre-defined chunks of HTML into a RTE field. You could have a pre-defined piece of HTML which might have some identifier to indicate it should use custom processing (I would suggest some `data-xxx` style attribute which would not conflict with any CSS or JavaScript). Then you could create a new `renderField` pipeline processor which would detect the `data-xxx` attribute within the content of a rich text field - you would use HtmlAgilityPack for this and then replace that snippet with the contents of your server-side file.

-or-

2) Split your text content into two separate chunks and have two instances of a "HtmlText" rendering within the placeholder, with a rendering for your quote text between them in the same placeholder.

I would advise that having a rule to insert text after the second paragraph would be quite 'brittle' as this would be very reliant on content editors setting the rich text field contents in quite a precise way e.g. to always ensure two or more paragraphs and to always break text with paragraphs - they might decide to use a load of line breaks instead to split their text. That said if you did do this, you would create a new renderField pipeline processor.